# FineUploader - Can I upload files in relative path I send client side?

Tags: fine-uploader

I have intergrated fine uploader to a form and when I upload files they are stored into the folder I specified e.g. files and in seperate subfolder and each of them has the files uuid as a name.
In a project I have I produce a dynamic path for every upload programmatically client side which could be relative path under global upload folder. How can I pass this relative path (which is different for every file)  to every file upload and then how the endpoint.php can see this path and generate the folder and save the uploading file?

Comment: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setEndpoint

Comment: I mean at the same upload to save each file to specific and probably different relative path under global upload target folder

Comment: don't understand, please rephrase

Comment: For example I have to upload  100 files. I process all of them and according to the content of each file I want to put them in seperate folders. For example if each file contains one word, the name of a color, I want all the files contain the word yellow to be saved into folder yellow, all containing the word blue into the folder blue and so on. The part of the process of files is finished. At this time I am finishing the whole modification, using the uuid and modifying the handler.php and endpoint.php but I wanted if possible something quick using the api.

Comment: You can use the API method from my first comment to set the endpoint per file using whatever logic you desire.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. As my implementation is complicated I will try it for sure!

Answer (score 0):

For changing the folder where fineuploader uploads to:

Open **handler.php**, find the line;

```
$target = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array($uploadDirectory, $uiid, $name));
```

change it to

```
$target = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array($uploadDirectory, "the_folder_you_want", $name));
```

This would upload all the images to your specified folder and not on individual generated *uiid* directories.